# extracting audio from video avi file

Tags: video

Hi every one i am doing a project on emotion recognition in audiovisual signal. I have taken an avi format video as input and extracted audio from it.. But the extracted audio is not the same as in video. Can any one help me how to get the audio file that plays in the same rate as in video.. here is the code snippet that i have used..

```
enter code here

clc;
clear all;
close all;
file='pro1.avi';
file1='vipmen1.wav'; %o/p file name
hmfr=video.MultimediaFileReader(file,'AudioOutputPort',true,'VideoOutputPort',false);
hmfw = video.MultimediaFileWriter(file1,'AudioInputPort',true,'FileFormat','WAV');

while ~isDone(hmfr)
audioFrame = step(hmfr);
step(hmfw,audioFrame);
end
close(hmfw);
close(hmfr);
```

thank you